# Apache Camel VM queue between servlets

Tags: apache-camel, endpoint

I'm trying to setup simple VM queue test between two servlets without success. The problem is that the request always timeouts as there is no response, OUT message, within expected timeframe.

"org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 30000 millis."

The servlets are running in Tomcat and are both deploying Apache Camel. Both apps are defining camel context and simple routes. The basic setup should be fine as simple routes like following are working:

```
<route>
  <from uri="servlet:///hello?servletName=app1" />
    <transform>
      <simple>Hello world</simple>
    </transform>
</route>

<route>
  <from uri="servlet:///hello?servletName=app2" />
    <transform>
      <simple>Hello world</simple>
    </transform>
</route>
```

First of all I'm not sure if the message ever reaches the app2 as the same timout happens even if the requested route wouldn't be even defined (the app2 would be missing the VM route). So the problem could be in how to define the route between two servlets using VM queue.

If the route between the servlets is fine then the problem should be in the missing/incorrect reply. I do understand that the receiving end should return the reply as the incoming requst from web server is inOut type, but I don't know how to achieve that.

The route in app1 receiving the web request:

```
<route>
  <from uri="servlet:///test?servletName=app1" />
  <to uri="vm:test">
</route>
```

and the other end in servlet app2:

```
<route>
  <from uri="vm:test" />
// Tested here: output with <simple>, 'To', 'inOut'... the result is always timeout
</route>
```

As I'm new with Apache Camel the root cause is most likely very simple. Any help would be highly appreciated.

The question is simply, how to setup VM queue between two servlet apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vm component works in the same classloader, eg kinda what we say on the vm documentation page: http://camel.apache.org/vm.html

> This component differs from the SEDA component in that VM supports
>   communication across CamelContext instances - so you can use this
>   mechanism to communicate across web applications (provided that
>   camel-core.jar is on the system/boot classpath).

So if you use Apache Tomcat, you need to have camel-core JAR as shared JAR. Such as in the boot classpath somewhere.

Comment: I totally missed the part that the camel-core JAR needs to be shared. I will need to now figure out how to package the .war's without embedding the camel-core and instead use shared one. I will update the results here after I get everything done. Thanks Claus.

Comment: Now the problem is that if I move only the camel-core into Tomcat shared libraries folder the servlet stops working as there is apparently some class loader conflict related to Log dependencies. If I also move the log dependencies (standard dependencies coming from Maven Apache camel template) under the shared libraries there is another class loader related linkage error. Do I really need to figure out which JAR's to move to shared folder or is there some known set of packages what must located with camel-core or some other way? What is the best practice to setup camel-core as shared JAR?

Comment: The problem with dependencies was solved by configuring logging properly and restarting Tomcat.

Comment: Hi I have the same issue with the Log class causing linkage errors, would you mind explaining how you fixed this in more detail? I am not sure what you mean by "configuring logging properly" Many thanks